# Conditionally add/remove property from element with React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have this TextField element. I want to conditionally add either `value={x}` or `defaultValue={x}`

this will work (without any conditionals)

```
<TextField
    id="pickupName"
    className="order-form-input"
    onBlur={this.fieldChange('name')}
    ref="pickupName"
    defaultValue={(order.pickup || {}).name || ''}
    // hintText="Pickup Contact Name"
    floatingLabelFixed={true}
    floatingLabelText="Contact Name"
/>
```

however, if I try to add conditionals (of course it will fail):

```
<TextField
    id="pickupName"
    className="order-form-input"
    onBlur={this.fieldChange('name')}
    ref="pickupName"
      {true ? defaultValue={(order.pickup || {}).name || ''} :
                            value={(order.pickup || {}).name || ''}}
    // hintText="Pickup Contact Name"
    floatingLabelFixed={true}
    floatingLabelText="Contact Name"
/>
```

is there a way to have the `defaultValue` or `value` properties point to functions instead of static strings? Given my need, I have to conditionally use either `value` or `defaultValue` because they behave quite differently.

Comment: Maybe you should just use `value`.

Comment: yes but if I use value, then I have to use onChange, which is overkill, updating for every keystroke..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using es6 you parse all remaining arguments in the end of component declaration using `{...args}` operator.

Example:

```
<TextField
    id="pickupName"
    className="order-form-input"
    onBlur={this.fieldChange('name')}
    ref="pickupName"
    floatingLabelFixed={true}
    floatingLabelText="Contact Name",
    {...extra_args}
    />
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: thanks! can you show an example of what extra_args might look like? array or plain object?